# is there any way to backup generated pdf report files from jasperserver?

Tags: tomcat, jasper-reports, report, jasperserver

I've been running jaspperserver (deployed on  tomcat 6) for a while now. In my daily report folder I have quite a huge number of files.

I'm wondering if there is a way to back them up and delete them from that folder so that I have an empty daily report folder again.

Comment: Folks...just because something has the word "server" in it doesn't make it all right to migrate to Server Fault.

Comment: @Kev: Strictly speaking, this is a "how do I use program X" question, not a programming question.

Comment: @black sensei: I would recommend asking this question at JasperForge.

Comment: ok. the reason why i've asked here is that, people are fast responding here and are really experienced. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could download them via the webservice interface of jasperserver in a script and then safe them somewhere. And then delete them on the server.

Or you could just take a backup of the jasperserver database (which contains the pdf files) and delete them afterwards. But then you would have to do a restore to download them later.. and that might be a problem if you upgraded jasperserver version.

You could even just run a separate jasper server off the database copy...